# About proving the logical syntactic axiom 3's reverse by using, (deducing from), axiom1 and 2.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms

The syntactic axioms here are

1. $\forall p,q \in L : p\Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow p)$
2. $\forall p,q,r \in L : (p\Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r))\Rightarrow ( (p\Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow (p \Rightarrow r) )$
3. $ \forall p \in L : \neg \neg p \Rightarrow p$

We know that axioms 3 independent from 1 and 2, however, its reverse

$ \forall p \in L : p\Rightarrow  \neg \neg p $ is not.

So exactly how to show the above reverse by using axiom1 and 2?

I firstly change it into a more original form

$a\Rightarrow ((a\Rightarrow\bot)\Rightarrow\bot)$.

By using the Completeness Theorem, such a question will be trivial, so if not using it but simply use Deduction Lemma, I wonder how to show this. I tried a long time but didn't succeed so I wonder if my method is not correct.

Comment: If you can use the deduction theorem, it seems like it should be easy: $\{ a, a \Rightarrow \bot \} \vdash \bot$ by a simple modus ponens, so by the deduction theorem, $\{ a \} \vdash (a \Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow \bot$, so by the deduction theorem again, $\vdash a \Rightarrow ((a \Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow \bot)$.

Comment: I guess, if you don't have any specific axiom expressing $\bot$ as the falsehood, it is pointless to translate $\lnot a$ as $a \to \bot$. Who is $\bot$? How can you distinguish $\bot$ front any other propositional variable? Said differently, I don't think that your axioms are complete. From your axioms,  can you derive $(\lnot p \to \lnot q) \to (q \to p) $? If yes, I have a very simple solution to your problem. But I don't think you can derive that formula from your axioms, because you don't have any axiom that tell you how to deal with formulas with just one negation.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco It is complete, using that $\neg a$ is an abbreviation for $a\rightarrow\bot$, it is possible to  prove $((p\rightarrow\bot)\rightarrow(q\rightarrow\bot))\rightarrow q\rightarrow((p\rightarrow\bot)\rightarrow\bot)$. The lambda calculus term $\lambda f.\lambda x.\lambda g.g(fx)$ shows that this is possible by the [Curry-Howard Correspondance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) and the equivalence of typed [SK calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) with simply typed lambda calculus. 
[contd.]

Comment: Combining that with double negation elimination applied to the conseqent via a construction similar to hypothetical syllogism we get $((p\rightarrow\bot)\rightarrow(q\rightarrow\bot))\rightarrow q\rightarrow p$.

Additionally explosion may be derived via $\bot\rightarrow((a\rightarrow\bot)\rightarrow\bot)$ and double negation elimination using hypothetical syllogism.

Comment: There is a small error in my first comment. The lambda term should have been $\lambda f.\lambda x.\lambda g.(fg)x$